# Module-specific database config in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want one of my Zend Framework modules to use a different database from the others. [The Manual suggests](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.modules) you can prefix the resources in `application.ini` with the module name to achieve this but I can't get it to work.

The relevant bits of my `application.ini` are:

```
resources.modules[] = ""

resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.dbname = "maindb"
resources.db.params.username = "dbuser"
resources.db.params.password = "..."
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"

terms.resources.db.params.dbname = "termsdb"
```

where `terms` is the name of the module.

Is there something special I need to put in the Bootstrap to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

In regards to the OP's first comment below...

No I cant elaborate on setting up a modular DB resource. What i provided should work in theory i believe. If it doesnt im not sure what needs to be modified in an extension of `Zend_Application_Resource_Db` because as i eluded to i dont use that resource. I have my own custom resource that allows for multiple dbs and fetching those db connections based on unique connection names. I can however ellaborate on that :-)

So i have a `MyLib_Db` class that extends `Zend_Db` it looks something like this:

```
class MyLib_Db extends Zend_Db
{
   protected $_instance = null;
   protected $_connections = array();

   /**
    * Standard Zend Framework unified constructor
    * @param null|array An array of options that will be passed to setOptions
    */
   public function __construct($options = null)
   {
   }

   /**
    * Standard Zend Framework setOptions implementation
    * @param array $options and array of options from config
    * @return MyLib_Db
    */
   public function setOptions(array $options)
   {
   }

   /**
    * Set the class instance
    * @param MyLib_Db
    * @return MyLib_Db
    */
   public static function setInstance($instance)
   {
   }

   /**
    * Get/create the singleton instance
    * @return MyLib_Db
    */
   public static function getInstance()
   {
   }

   /**
    * Get a Zend_Db adapter Instance by unique name
    * Searches self::$_connections for the $name param as an array key
    * @param String $name unique connection name
    * @return Zend_Db_Adpater_Abstract|null
    */
   public function getConnection($connectionName)
   {
   }

   /**
    * Add a connection instance to the registry
    * Adds/creates an Zend_Db_Adapter instance to the connection registry with
    * the string key provided by $name. If $connection is an array|Zend_Config it 
    * should match the format used by Zend_Db::factory as it will be passed to this   
    * function. If $name is null then the database name will be used. 
    * @param Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract|Zend_Config|array The connection to register
    * @param string|null $name A unique name for the connection
    * @return MyLib_Db
    */
   public function addConnection(Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract $connection, $name = null)
   {
   }

   /**
    * Remove/Destroy the specified connection from the registry
    * @param string $name the connection name to remove
    * @return MyLib_Db
    */
   public function removeConnection($name)
   {
   }
}
```

So basically my application resource for DB creates and returns an instance of the preceeding class. During creation it creates any adapters i have set up in my configuration and registers them in this class instance with a name (it also looks for a default flag for use with `Zend_Db_Table` as well as doing some other stuff).

Then i either use `MyLib_Db::getInstance()->getConnection($name);`
or i get the `MyLib_Db` instance from the bootstrap and then call `getConnection`.

Personally i prefer to do it this way because its not dependent on having a connection being app wide or tied to a specific module which allows for more flexible reuse. That said i actually have only used this on a couple projects because on most of my Zend projects Ive been using Doctrine instead of `Zend_Db`.

Hope that helps :-)

---

Actually i think you need to put that in your Module's section in the config like `modules.terms.resources.db.*`. This should make it load in the module bootstrap. Alternatively you could manullay set it up with an `_initDb` in your `Terms_Bootstrap`.

Personally though i use a special DB management class and put that in my resources instead - it handles setting a single or multiple adapters. Then assiming in the following that `$db` is the manager retrieved from the resources array...

`$dbAdapter = $db->getConnection('terms');`

Comment: The first suggestion doesn't work for me. Could you elaborate on how to set it up within the Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows:

```
moduleName.host = "localhost"
moduleName.username = "user"
moduleName.password = "pass"
moduleName.dbname = "dbname"
moduleName.charset = "utf8"
```

Then add following in your Module's Bootstrap.php in any init function

```
$params = $GLOBALS['application']->getOption('moduleName');
$dbAdapter = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL', array(
    'host' => $params['host'],
    'dbname' => $params['dbname'],
    'username' => $params['username'],
    'password' => $params['password'],
    'charset'  => $params['charset'],
));
Zend_Registry::set('moduleSpecific', $dbAdapter);
```

Then in your module's `model/DbTable/` folder create a class as follows and let your table classess to extend ModuleName_Model_DbTable_Tablemain instead of Zend_Db_Table_Abstract and you are ready to go.

```
class ModuleName_Model_DbTable_Tablemain extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    /**
     * 
     * wrapper class constructor used to set db adaptor on the fly
     * @author Krishan
     */
    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct($adapter = Zend_Registry::get('moduleSpecific'));

    }
}
```

let me know in case of any problem